# Coupon daily time range in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, date-range, coupon

I'm tying to enable the use of coupons to a range of hours in Woocommerce without success.

Based on [Discount on specific products based on a daily time range in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024563/discount-on-specific-products-based-on-a-daily-time-range-in-woocommerce/53027045#53027045) answer, my code is:

```
// Utility function that gives the discount daily period
function get_discount_period_rate(){
    // Set the correct time zone  (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');


    // Set the start time and the end time
    $start_time = mktime( 08, 00, 00, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y") );
    $end_time   = mktime( 09, 00, 00, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y") );
    $time_now   = strtotime("now");
}

    // Set the coupon Ids that will be discounted
  $wc_coupon = new WC_Coupon('integralia10'); // get intance of wc_coupon which code is "integralia10"
    if (!$wc_coupon || !$wc_coupon->is_valid()) {
        return;
    }

    $coupon_code = $wc_coupon->get_code();
    if (!$coupon_code) {
        return;
    }
```

Also, I Would like to use the `wc_print_notices` function to show a message when somemeone try to use the Coupon code out of time range.

Any Sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, all coupons that fall within a certain time frame will be valid, if not, an error message will be displayed.

**Please set:**

- The correct [time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
- The start and end time

```php
function time_range() {
    // Set the correct time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Brussels' );

    // Set the start time and the end time to be valid
    $start_time = mktime( 11, 00, 00, date( 'm' ), date( 'd' ), date( 'y' ) );
    $end_time   = mktime( 18, 00, 00, date( 'm' ), date( 'd' ), date( 'y' ) );
    $time_now   = strtotime( 'now' );
    
    // Return true or false
    return $start_time <= $time_now && $end_time >= $time_now ? true : false;
}

// Is valid
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_is_valid( $valid, $coupon, $discount ) {
    // Call function, return true or false
    $valid = time_range();

    // NOT valid
    if ( ! $valid ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'My custom error message.', 'woocommerce' ), 109 );
    }

    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 10, 3 );
```

---

**UPDATE:** To apply the same, but only to certain coupons ID's,
use this instead.

```php
function time_range_coupon_id( $coupon_id ) {
    // For specific coupon ID's only, several could be added, separated by a comma
    $specific_coupons_ids = array( 107, 108 );
    
    // Coupon ID in array, so check
    if ( in_array( $coupon_id, $specific_coupons_ids ) ) {
        // Set the correct time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Brussels' );

        // Set the start time and the end time to be valid
        $start_time = mktime( 12, 00, 00, date( 'm' ), date( 'd' ), date( 'y' ) );
        $end_time   = mktime( 17, 00, 00, date( 'm' ), date( 'd' ), date( 'y' ) );
        $time_now   = strtotime( 'now' );
        
        // Return true or false
        return $start_time <= $time_now && $end_time >= $time_now ? true : false;
    }
    
    // Default
    return true;
}

// Is valid
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_is_valid( $valid, $coupon, $discount ) {
    // Get coupon ID
    $coupon_id = $coupon->get_id();
    
    // Call function, return true or false
    $valid = time_range_coupon_id( $coupon_id );

    // NOT valid
    if ( ! $valid ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'My error message', 'woocommerce' ), 109 );
    }

    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 10, 3 );
```